# Number of partitions of $n$ in which parts can occur at most 7 times

Tags: graph-theory, notation, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I have got the following answer without detailing the whole answer as I am looking precisely for the notation used here as I am new to graph theory, so please pardon me. After a series of operations, I got the following

$$A(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} p(n)q^n = ... = \frac{1}{(9^6\times9^6)_{\infty}(9^6\times9^6)_{\infty}
(9^6\times9^2)_{\infty}(9^4\times9^6)_{\infty}}$$

What does $\infty$ notation here referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bad OCR scan.  I suspect that some of the $9$s are supposed to be $q$s, and you have mixed up $x$ and $q$.

If $p(n)$ is the number of such partitions, the correct generating function is
$$A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n) x^n = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^7 x^{ki} = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1-x^{8k}}{1-x^k}$$

Comment: Thank you. So $\infty$ is just scan error. How you get the final formula $\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1-x^{8k}}{1-x^k}$?

Comment: Use the finite geometric series formula $\sum_{i=0}^m r^i = \frac{1-r^{m+1}}{1-r}$ with $r=x^k$ and $m=7$.

Comment: But this is infinite series, so probably you mean $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: No, the inner sum over $i$ is finite, with 8 terms.